# Dynamically created gridview full column data, how to get in to a textbox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i have one grid view table loading data from sql, number of columns will be dynamically loaded different number each in each time. 
sql data look like this

```
[ID        NAME
1   ALANKIT HEALTH CARE LTD
2   APOLLO MUNICH HEALTH INSURANCE COMPANY LTD
3   BAJAJ ALLIANZ GENERAL INSURANCE COMPANY LIMITED
4   DEDICATED HEALTHCARE SERVICES (INDIA) PVT LTD
5   E MEDITEK (TPA) SERVICES LTD
6   FAMILY HEALTH PLAN LIMITED
7   FUTURE GENERALI INDIA INSURANCE
8   GENINS INDIA LIMITED
9   GOOD HEALTH PLAN LIMITED
10  HDFC ERGO GENRAL INSURANCE COMPANY LIMITED ]
```

and the list go on.
help is required to get dynamically loaded NAME column full data need to get in to a single text box.

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Need to save data loaded TextBox to SQL, because each time data will be different

Comment: A bit more clear?